# Using Google Static Maps with API v3 - need an updated reference please!

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

The guide *[Using Static Maps to Speed Up Your Dynamic Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/static+js.html)* is painfully out of date.

Can you help show me what this should look like with API v3? I'm specifically interested in the tail end of the process, involving the callback, etc.

I've already got this figured out:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', removeStaticMap);
```

**EDIT:**

Am I correct in that the proper initialization would be using [this technique](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async.html) (with the loadScript)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a static map - the v3 API actually loads a static map first and then swaps it out when the tiles are loaded.

Comment: I'd read that in passing, but certainly don't observe it in practice. Besides, I'm also do this so that when JS is disabled an image (just ≈22kb jpeg of the map at the canvas size I'm using) is displayed instead of a large gaping hole on the screen. Worth the modest overhead.